# going south/haywire/pear-shaped etc

Tags: phrase-meaning

I had a sudden *satori* (can one have an unsudden *satori*? :-) when reading "Südpfeil" ("south arrow", for "downvote") in a German forum. Since North is (almost) always upwards on a map, the meaning from "going south" stems from "going down". (Always guessed - please don't burst my bubble...)

I also know ["going pear-shaped"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/197243/im-having-trouble-understanding-why-go-pear-shaped-has-the-negative-meaning), but the etymology seems to have gone lost in the fog of time.

What about "going haywire"? A haywire probably is a wire the peasant uses to wrap up hay (too lazy to check...). No idea where this is going...Any idea about the etymology of the phrase?

P.S. Feel free to add another synonym with "going". (I only found "going down like a lead balloon/zeppelin", the metapher being obvious.)

Comment: If you try out "went down like a Zeppelin" that will very likely be taken as a pejorative remark, and I shy away from saying exactly how it goes down, but it is not "like a lead balloon" and is not an idiomatic simile. "Go haywire" is something that happens quite rapidly to instruments, plans, etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane - how can we forget Lakehurst? However I think Hauke was supplying balloon and Zeppelin as alternative things made of lead that might be expected to tend to want to go downwards rapidly.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey you remind me of a joke about Pierre, the famous fighter pilote, whose punch line was "when I ger down, I ger down in flems!"

Comment: @WeatherVane -  arrête tes blagues !

Comment: @MichaelHarvey once upon a time, before I ever heard of the expression "pear shaped" I made the *faux pas* of telling an attractive friend she was pear shaped (she was lovely). It went down like a... a...

Comment: @WeatherVane - which way up was the pear in your mind?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey horizontal ;)

Comment: You forgot: going berserk. go=become

Comment: I had to look up the meaning of _satori_!

Comment: I don't actually see a single, answerable question here.

Comment: @DoneWithThis: The question is the thingy with the "?" at the end, i.e. the metapher with haywire. But the answer below satisfactorily explained why haywire can go haywire :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have always suspected (although I have no proof) that when a situation goes pear-shaped', it sags or slumps into failure, like a flexible sphere in which the contents have slipped downwards, or like peoples' bodies in obese middle age (when everything *goes south*, in fact). Haywire is steel wire supplied wound into tight coils under tension. If released carelessly it can jump about in a wild fashion, as any released spring can do. Zeppelin is a proper noun and starts with a capital Z. (a Zeppelin is a type of rigid airship named after the German inventor Count Ferdinand von Zeppelin).

We can discuss the reception that things get by saying that they 'go down' well, badly, brilliantly, dismally, etc, and we can be more inventive and say that they go down like a cup of cold sick, or a turd at a picnic, a fat child on a see-saw. etc. Expressions can be made up on the spur of the moment.

If you are asking more generally about expressions using 'go' to mean 'enter a state or condition', there are too many to list, and are created all the time: go topless, go beserk, go Dutch, go loco (down in Acapulco?), go commando (uncomfortable in cheap jeans), and a thousand others.